# What is the best way to query a table and insert all rows back into itself with two columns switched?

Tags: sql, select

I have the following columns and an example row:

```
ID COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4

1  dat1  dat2  dat3  dat4
```

I want to perform a query that will leave me with this:

```
ID COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4

1  dat1  dat2  dat3  dat4

2  dat2  dat1  dat3  dat4
```

I was experimenting but so far not been able to achieve this, my last attempt:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL1, COL2)
SELECT COL2, COL1 DAT3 DAT4 FROM TABLE1
```

Any advice or tips are much appreciated.

Comment: `INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
SELECT COL2, COL1, 'dat3', 'dat4' FROM TABLE1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use all the column in insert and you can get the value for selecct

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
SELECT COL2, COL1, COL3, COL4  FROM TABLE1;
```

for adding new values  you can

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
SELECT COL2, COL1, 'new_value_for_col3', 'new_value_for_col4' FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks exactly what I am looking for! I am curious, how would this work if I wanted to do this but also put new data into COL3 and COL4, would I do this: COL1, COL2, 'new3', 'new4'?

Comment: @deucalion0  yes .. correct if you need that one or more column have new value you must set the correspondant position with the value you need ..

Comment: Could you kindly update your answer to show me the correct syntax? I cannot get it to work, I have tried this: 
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) SELECT COL2, COL1 from TABLE1, 'new3', 'new4'

Comment: I have update the answer  .. (supposing the col3 and col4 are string

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much this is perfect and solved my problem.